# Lazy loading with search engine optimization server get requests

Tags: javascript, performance, lazy-loading, cdn

Firstly I want to explain my objective,
I'm working on a lazy loading script for product list page allows search engine image search optimization.

Step 1: I'm using html like this

```
<img alt="{seo_name}" src="{img_source}">
```

Step 2: I'm transferring src attributes to another. And replace it with default image.

Step 3: I'm handling scroll event and positions to show images.

But when I do that im still sending requests. Abort them later. Like this.
[image]

Two Questions.

Is that costs money for CDN servers?
How can I cancel requests from an image?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. Why do you replace valid image urls with those of a default image? And then change it back or what?

Comment: im replacing them for "not loading image" and taking back them to load them.